# Как мне удалить класс navbar-nav когда размеры экрана ниже 992px?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.btn');
let main = document.querySelector('main')
button.onclick = function() {
  main.classList.toggle('transform');
  main.classList.toggle('untransform-menu');
};
```

```css
body{
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
}

.row{
 margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.location-container{
 display: inline;
}

.contacts-container{
 display: flex;
 background-color: #0f0e4d;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 0;
}

.instagram-img{
 background: white;
}

.tel-container, .email-container, .location-container{
 display: flex;
 align-items: flex-end;
}

label{
 margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.tel-link{
 text-decoration: none !important;
 color: #419FE1;
 transition: color 0.3s linear;
 margin-left: 8px;
}


.tel-link:hover{
 color: #0048BA;
}

.email-label, .location-label{
 padding-left: 8px;
}

.navbar-default{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 background-color: white !important;
 border: none !important;
}

.logo-site{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 margin-right: 64px;
}

.navbar-nav{
 margin-left: 64px !important;
}

.nav-link{
 color: #3F3E71 !important;
 transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out !important;
}

li{
 position: relative;
}

.nav-link:before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 3px;
 background-color: #FFDB00;
 width: 0;
 transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-link:hover{
 color: #FFDB00 !important;
}

.nav-link:hover:before{
 width: 100%;
}


.background-container{
 background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 117, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 117, 0.7)), url('../assets/img/background1.png') center center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}

.label-container{
 padding-top: 128px;
 padding-bottom: 256px;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: 64px;
}

.features{
 position: relative;
}

.feature{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -140px;
 width: 344px;
 color: white;
 transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}

.feature:hover{
 transform: translateY(-40px);
 cursor: pointer;
}

.feature:first-child{
 background-color: #3877F2;
}

.feature:nth-child(2){
 background-color: #A8C95A;
}

.feature:last-child{
 background-color: #F15B5B;
}

.feature-image-content{
 padding: 32px 16px;
 padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.feature-p-content, .feature-h2-content{
 padding-left: 16px;
}

.feature-p-content{
 font-size: 18px;
}

.strip{
 background: #444 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    width: 32px;
}

.strip:first-child{
 margin-top: 0px !important;
}

.btn-strip{
 border: 1px solid black !important;
 border-radius: 0px !important;
 padding: 10px !important;
}

main{
 transition: transform 0.3s linear; 
}

.transform{
 transform: translateY(-150px);
}

.untransform-menu{
 transform: translateY(150px);
}


@keyframes down1 {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  10% {
    height: 10px;
  }
  25% {
    height: 25px;
  }
  40% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  50% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  60% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  75% {
    height: 75px;
  }
  80% {
    height: 80px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100px;
  }
}

.btn-strip:focus ~ .dropdown-menu {
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
  animation-name: down1;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-group{
 margin: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 992px){
 .instagram-img{
  visibility: hidden;
 }
 .location-container{
  display: inline-block;
 }
 .tel-container{
  display: inline-block;
 }
 .email-container{
  display: inline-block;
 }

 .contacts-container{
  text-align: left;
 }

 .row .contacts-container{
  text-align: center !important;
 }

}
@media (max-width: 360px){
 .instagram-img{
  visibility: hidden;
 }
 .location-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
 }
 .tel-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
 }
 .email-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
 }

 .contacts-container{
  text-align: left;
 }

 .row .contacts-container{
  text-align: left !important;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <title>Training Project</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
 <header> 
  <ul class="row contacts-container container-fluid">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="test">
     <div class="col-md-2 tel-container">
      <i class="material-icons">call</i>
      <a href="tel:+375292381636" class="tel-link">+375292381636</a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 email-container">
      <i class="material-icons">email</i>
      <label class="email-label">info@brain-it.by</label>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 location-container">
      <i class="material-icons">add_location</i>
      <label class="location-label">Брест, Республика Беларусь</label>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/brain_it_brest/">
       <img src="../assets/img/instagram-link.svg" class="instagram-img" width="16">
      </a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </ul>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default container">
   <div class="logo-site">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <a href="#">
      <img src="../assets/img/logo.png">
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="btn-group">
     <div class="btn-group">
       <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-strip">
         <span class="strip"></span>
         <span class="strip"></span>
         <span class="strip"></span>
       </button>
       <!-- Выпадающее меню -->
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <!-- Пункты меню -->
         <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
         <li class="divider"></li>
         <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">О школе</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Курсы</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Вопрос-ответ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Контакты</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
 <main>
  <div class="background-container">
   <div class='label-container'>
    <label>BrainIT поможет войти в АйТи</label>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row features">
     <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 feature">
      <img src="../assets/img/person.png" class="feature-image-content">
      <h2 class="feature-h2-content">Эффективные методики</h2>
      <p class="feature-p-content">Прогрессивные техники обучения и индивидуальный подход к каждому студенту</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 feature">
      <img src="../assets/img/book.png" class="feature-image-content">
      <h2 class="feature-h2-content">Визуальные материалы</h2>
      <p class="feature-p-content">Интеллект-карты и мнемонические структуры, увеличивающие усвоение информации в разы</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 feature">
      <img src="../assets/img/support.png" class="feature-image-content">
      <h2 class="feature-h2-content">Сопровождение до трудоустройства</h2>
      <p class="feature-p-content">После окончания курса Вас бесплатно будет сопровождать ментор, пока не трудоустроитесь</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </main>
 <footer>
 </footer>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/delete.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [media-запросы](https://itchief.ru/lessons/html-and-css/css-media-queries). В `css` можно прописать

```
@media max-width: 992px {
// обнуление стилей вашего класса
}
```

Если нужно через `js`, то там есть возможность прописать через условие

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 992px)").matches && window.matchMedia("(max-height: 992px)").matches) {
     Obj.classList.remove ("navbar-nav");
}
```

Где Obj — объект у которого надо удалить класс